# Changing permalink name redirects to another template?

Tags: permalinks, pages, templates, page-template

I'm creating a template with a few templates with names `page-contact.php`, `page-portfolio.php` and `page-blog.php`.

The problem is that when I select a **Defaul Template** for a page (I expect it to open `page.php`) and rename the page permalink to **sitename.com/contact** the page starts using the `page-contact.php`..

Why is that, why is the URL telling WordPress what template to use if a Default one i chosen? Is this intended behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is the intended behaviour:

> page-{slug}.php - If the page slug is recent-news, WordPress will look
>   to use page-recent-news.php

So, simply use a different filename for your templates, like template-contact.php for example. You can find more info about this here:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy